What is the best way to submit a mathematical solution to a university?
I have an indisputable proof of the Collatz conjecture and I am trying to submit it to a school. Should I approach a professor or the president of the University if I am offering half of the prize money for their assistance in publishing my work?

Why would you want to submit it to a university? Universities don’t publish papers. Why not approach a regular publisher/journal or even a direct publication platform such as arxiv?

Please see the linked question. The relevance might not be immediately obvious, but it is: you are making a very bold claim ("indisputable proof" of a famous open problem) and you need to convince someone (probably not a university, but a professor or publisher) to spend time reviewing your work.

Thank you so much for your replies. The reason why I wanted to go to a university or specifically a professor is because I could show it to them, and they would be taken seriously because of the PhD with their name. I have two main concerns about sending it off to be reviewed. It has never been published because if you see it, there is no way you cannot understand it and I am worried that they would Zuckerberg me change the font and color of the text and claim it as their own. It is worth a lot of money and I know it’s value and it’s clarity. Is this something I should be worrying about?

@Kevinswag "Indisputable"/"there is no way you cannot understand it" - both are things that need a third party to voice their opinion about. It is very easy to think something is clear when it actually isn't (see the Hales/Kepler Conjecture debate). Independently, you do not go and offer prize money for reviewing your work. If the person has integrity (and that's what you look for), they will be offended. Collatz would be an amazing achievement for anyone, but an honest scientist will not steal glory and won't be in for the money.

I agree with the captain: any mathematician of integrity would want you to get the credit and would be happy just to be involved as an advocate. But, expect skepticism. You are claiming that you, with limited mathematical training, have spotted something obvious enough that "if you see it, there is no way you cannot understand it," but hundreds of actual mathematicians have somehow all missed it over the last century. Statistically, this would be almost unprecedented. Even when amateurs have made real contributions, the proofs are usually hundreds of pages long and take a long time to verify.

Wow guys. I really feel like the Earth is playing a prank on me right now there is no way this problem was worth $1 million. Somebody’s gonna wake me up. Due to the laws of limitation’s the answer I have is unquestionable indisputable and obvious once it’s shown. I really think one of you guys  is setting me up somehow Good thing I’m not schizophrenic it’s just that was just way too easy. Somebody told me to go look for it just seems like a set up anyway, I will keep you posted. I finally have the courage to send it off and not worry about it being stolen.
