What safety measure is recommended when sending in paper for peer review
How do I ensure that the person doing the peer review of my work does not steal the intellectual property? I am asking because this paper is worth $1 million prize.

Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65817/how-can-an-author-get-assurance-that-his-work-will-not-be-stolen-by-journal-staf

If this is what you are worried about, instead of correctness of the paper, it is most likely wrong. In math, physics and theoretical CS people typically post their papers on arXiv before sending them to journals.

Given that you've said this paper is worth a million dollars, it sounds like you think you've proven one of the Millennium problems.  There are a lot of people who claim to have done this sort of thing, and they are almost inevitably wrong.  That you are worried about this suggests you have very little background in math. Trying to jump to a Millennium problem with no prior mathematical research is like a person in 1800 trying to build a rocket to take people to the moon. This is not going to be productive or at all likely to succeed.

@JoshuaZ: indeed, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/215730/what-is-the-best-way-to-submit-a-mathematical-solution-to-a-university (Collatz conjecture)

@BenBolker Ah, so not a Millennium problem, but another famous problem with prize money.

I have proof the collatz conjecture, and in doing so my method has revealed that if I publish it, your encryption and security are in jeopardy. How do I proceed from here. If I am not taken, seriously, I proceed with publishing starting Monday.

@Kevinswag  Your claims in your last comment make it even less likely that you have discovered anything at all. It is unlikely there's any deep connection between Collatz and encryption. However, this sort of extremely grandiose claim is made by people all the time with no mathematical background who claim to have solved major problems. Do you think all the others who claim to have solved the Riemann Hypothesis, or resolved P != NP, or proven there are are no odd perfect numbers were at all likely to be correct? Why do you think you are different than any of them?

The main safety measure is to send the paper to only reputable journals. It would take a conspiracy to steal the ideas and a miracle to get them published by someone else before you do.
Relax. Almost everyone is honest and reviewers are chosen for their ethical behavior as well as their knowledge of field.
If it isn't for publication, then make sure that you send it to people you can trust. These should be people with a reputation to protect.
In some cases, such as a prize competition, you might be able to submit it to the prize organization first.
But, there are no absolutes in this world. Overthinking it can lead to ulcers, though.
In extreme cases, one could file a sealed copy of a paper with a lawyer who dates and retains the copy. This would offer some, but probably not absolute protection, though at a cost. Older schemes had people mail themself a copy of the work and leaving it sealed on arrival, presumably dated by the postal authorities, though that dating might require an extra cost mail option.

To have a more rounded answer, you might mention Müller and Bednorz who discovered high-temperature supraconductivity in 1987. Since this was a major breakthrough and easy to reproduce, they were worried enough about being scooped that they announced it to the New York Times and submitted to a lesser known German physics journal with a trusted editor. People chastised them for not sending it to something like Science or Nature first, but obviously they had limited faith in their integrity in view of the temptations.

When 1.a discovery is an obvious breakthrough, 2. the author is not well known with a network of trusted people, 3. the idea is easy to understand and to appropriate, trust alone is not sufficient. Where arXiv is an option, it should be used. That being said, it is extremely rare that an outsider lands a major scoop and OP would be well advised to get opinions from trusted sources about their work.

I agree that arXiV would be the best way to establish precedence. arxiV submission will probably require an endorsement, which means OP would have to go through the process of getting opinions from trusted sources anyway ... https://vixra.org/ is dodgy https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105518/what-are-the-differences-between-vixra-org-and-arxiv-org but would presumably be an easier way to establish precedence ... (searching "collatz proof" on vixra gets 334 hits ...)

Thank you, Ben Bolker. Yes, I am very aware of all of the ridiculous attempts that I have seen. The approach that they have taken is juvenile from the beginning. My approach is what sets me apart. Many people will cry that they wasted so much time. I do appreciate everyone making their submissions public so that I can see why without seeing mine. They would think that any submission would be ridiculous. I agree everything I have seen other than mine is ridiculous.  I emphasize the word ridiculous again.
